# Is explicit ".prototype" really needed?

Tags: javascript

I often see something like this in other people's scripts:

```
bar = Array.prototype.slice.call(whatever, 1)
```

However, the following shorter notation works fine as well:

```
bar = [].slice.call(whatever, 1)
```

Are these two constructs fully equivalent? Are there engines (browsers) that treat them differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, fully equivalent.

It happens to be that the access via `.prototype` is slightly faster because no new object instance needs to get created. However, thats what we call *microoptimization*.

---

A nice way to get entirely rid of deep chaining, is to invoke `Function.prototype.bind`.

Example

```
(function( slice ) {
    slice( whatever, 1 );
}( Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.slice )));
```

Comment: As a side note, `[].slice.call(...)` makes no assumptions about Array. It will work regardless of whether `Array` has been redefined, which, IMO, should never happen. It's also shorter... so there's that. (microoptimization) :)

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent strictly speaking. This construction:

```
[].slice.call(whatever, 1)
```

allocates new instance of array on the heap just for the purpose of getting property from it.
So it has side effect - leaves garbage in the heap.